# How to remove clustering from vis.js

Tags: cluster-analysis, vis.js

I have clustering set on a vis.js network diagram. Adding nodes to cluster works. But I cannot remove a node from cluster. I believe the problem is that the first time the code below runs it creates a cluster, after I do some modification to the nodes (e.g. remove node from group) and I run it the second time it keeps the previous cluster and just adds the nodes (if any was added) but doesn't remove them (if any was removed).

So I think that removing all the cluster options and the applying it again should do the trick, but I cant find the way to achieve that.

```
  const clusterOption = {
    joinCondition: function (childOptions) {
      return childOptions.cid === group.groupId;
    },
    clusterNodeProperties: { 
      id: group.groupId, 
      label: group.label, 
      shape: 'database', 
      allowSingleNodeCluster: true 
    }
  };
  this.network.cluster(clusterOption);
```

So my idea would be to do something along the following lines (in pseudocode) before calling the above code.

`this.network.clearClusters();`

Answer (score 0):

Running `this.network.cluster(clusterOption);` again seems to work in my experiments (see http://jsfiddle.net/thomaash/t8q37Lsc/, though I adapted one of the examples since you didn't provide MWE). But this may be a bug. It seems to me that the cluster should be updated when the underlying nodes are updated. Do you plan to open an issue (https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/new)?

PS: What version are you using? People sometimes miss an update and then try to solve issues that are resolved in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function decluster() {
    for (index of network.body.nodeIndices) {
        if (network.isCluster(index) == true) {
            network.openCluster(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The network instance has a "isCluster" method which takes a node index as a parameter, that you can invoke to identify if a given node is a cluster. Once you have identified that a given node is a cluster, you can then invoke the "openCluster" method on the same network instance with the node index.

Below is a code snippet for a Vue3 implementation.

```
unclusterNodes() {
  for (const index of this.network.body.nodeIndices) {
    if (this.network.isCluster(index) == true) {
        this.network.openCluster(index);
    }
}
```